# Android imageview only accepts some jpg's

Tags: android, jpeg, imageview

I have an image view in my app. when I try to make it show a jpg file exported from 3ds max, it works. But if it comes from Photoshop, it just does nothing. Why is that? If it is at all important my app gets the image from my server with the following code:

```
public static Bitmap getWebImage(String URL)
{
    URL myImageURL = null;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {

        myImageURL = new URL(URL);

        } catch (MalformedURLException error) {


        error.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)myImageURL .openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);

            connection.connect();

            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            } catch (IOException e) {


            e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return bitmap;

}
```

Comment: Hi, have you solved this ? I am having exactly the same issue with Photoschop-produced jpeg's :(

Comment: Yes, when saving from photoshop, you need to go "save for web and devices".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible for you to upload the two pictures for comparison?

Comment: BTW, I resized the 2 file. but if I took the one that did work, opened it in photoshop, then just saved it, the new one would not work.

Comment: Hmm. Probably NOT the issue, since both images are Untagged RGB, but try doing Edit > Assign Profile, and assign it to sRGB.

Comment: Wait, how are you saving the file, out of curiosity? On the JPEG Save As dialog, what settings do you use?

Comment: Humor me and let me know what they are, though. :P Do you use Save for Web? Save As? If Save As, there are options along the bottom, then other options once you choose JPEG.

Comment: I go save as, Quality is 8, no matte, and the format options is Baseline ("Standard")

Comment: Try using Save for Web, and just pick JPEG High from the list of defaults. See if that works.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You gave me an idea to make it work, i went "Save for web and Devices" and it worked! Thanks for your time.

Comment: I posted that before I refreshed the page. Thanks.

Comment: lol you're welcome, glad it worked! Save for Web strips out all kind of metadata. Photoshop must have been saving something weird with it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the color settings of your JPG files? Most likely your JPG files from photoshop is in CMYK rather than RGB, and Android simply doesn't support CMYK.

Comment: Nope, it just simply does not appear.

Answer (score -2):

public static Bitmap getWebImage(String URL)
 {
 URL myImageURL = null;

Bitmap bitmap = null;

try {

myImageURL = new URL(URL);

} catch (MalformedURLException error) {

error.printStackTrace();

}
 try {

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)myImageURL .openConnection();

connection.setDoInput(true);

connection.connect();

InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

return bitmap;

}